# Searching for Wordpress plugin that can make restriction on posts/pages for specific users

Tags: wordpress

I need some plugin for WordPress that I can restrict some pages for specific users.

For instance, I have "USER 1" and "USER 2". I made new post/page and I say the only user logged in with "USER 1" account can see this post.

I already tried "User Specific Content" plugin but with this plugin, I can still see all the post with any user. The only content of the post is not visible to other users. I need just to see a list of post for a specific user.

So I need something if I post one thing and assign it to "USER 1" that other users cannot see any posts on the post page so only blank page and for instance "USER 1" will be able to see the post and to see the content of it.

Answer (score 0):

This Plugin allows you to select specific users by user name, or by role name who can view a specific post content or page content

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-specific-content/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-private-content-plus/

Comment: Understood that and both plugins are working fine. But if I have "post" page in menu and if I click on it I will redirect to the post page and I will be able to see all the post that I added. If I click to this specific post I will not be able to see content. Can I somehow block it from the list of all posts on the post page? So when I redirect to post page there to make restrictions not on content of post/page?

Comment: this one seems right for you as you asking 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-private-content-plus/

Comment: but with the pro version right? I applied to test pro for few day and I think it's available only on pro version. What do you think?